# Reactjs-ffsevents is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeError: fsevents is not a function
at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/FSEventsWatcher.js:162:20)
at createWatcher (/Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1052:23)
at Array.map ()
at HasteMap._watch (/Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1230:44)
at /Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:517:21
at Generator.next ()
at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:193:24)
at _next (/Users/ssurisettii/Desktop/Rewards /rewards_ui/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:213:9)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: add more detail + share code if possible

Comment: It is not a code error it is package error .so that why i am sayoing that Remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

1.do npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove *node_modules* folder and *package-lock.json* file

1.do npm install again.